# Generating metapackage artifacts with catkin_tools?

Tags: ros, catkin, bloom-release, metapackage, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My use case is non-standard.  I can't use the public Bloom infrastructure because I have non-public packages, and in the past, I created non-Bloom build scripts that helped me generate Debian packages. I can't easily replace them as they're pretty baked into our process.

Previously, with `catkin_make`, I could build a metapackage and it's `share/package_name/package.xml` would show up in the install path.  I used this to my advantage to create Debians for my metapackages.  My workflow was roughly:

1. Create a workspace `dep_ws` with the metapackage repo and all its dependencies in it.
2. Build the "dependency" workspace and source `dep_ws/install/setup.bash`.
3. Create a workspace `pkg_ws` with *only* the metapackage's repo in it.
4. Build the "package" workspace.

This resulted in a "clean" install space with just the metapackage in it, as all its dependencies were met in the dependency workspace.  I then dumped (more or less) the install path into a Debian and added the metapackage's dependencies as Debian dependencies.

I'm attempting to switch to `catkin_tools` as it provides many benefits, but I'm running into a problem recreating this workflow.  With `catkin build`, metapackage artifacts don't show up in the install path.  In fact, with `--summary`, it shows the metapackage being `[Ignored]` (even when I use `--whitelist` to only allow the metapackage to be built).

How do I generate metapackage artifacts with `catkin_tools`, such that I can Debianize them and get a "meta-Debian"?  Ultimately, the artifacts are important so that I can query the as-built metapackage for its dependencies and add them as Debian dependencies.  But if the metapackage's package.xml isn't in the install path, I have no way of doing that.

Or, am I [holding it wrong](http://www.cnn.com/2010/TECH/mobile/06/25/iphone.problems.response/index.html) and there's a different/better/correct way to do this (that doesn't involve all of Bloom)?  Should I simply treat metapackages differently than normal packages and have a different process for them (now)?

Follow-on:  If it is possible to generate metapackage artifacts with `catkin_tools`, I would also need it to *only* build the metapackage and not the `<exec_depend>`s.  Currently, even using `--whitelist`, if I `catkin build` the metapackage, all its `<exec_depend>`s get built, too, and pollute the "clean" install space.  Is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241107/generating-metapackage-artifacts-with-catkin_tools?/) by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2016-08-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like metapackages are not being built, which is not correct if that's what's happening. You should open a issue on catkin_tools. I guess it has to do with changes that Jonathan Bohren made related to avoiding the case where normal packages that incorrectly depend on metapackages caused catkin build to crash.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2016-12-29**:
Reported here: https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/418